# Expecting an 1x2 array but received a 2x2 array instead, in an Octave function

Tags: matlab, octave

```
function N1d = shapeFn1d(gp1d)
  n1 = 0.5*(1-gp1d(1,1));
  n2 = 0.5*(1+gp1d(2,1));

  N1d = [n1, n2];   
end
```

gp1d is a 2x1 array and I was expecting N1d to be a 1x2 array but it comes out to be as 2x2 array and I don't know why. Can someone please help me.

This is my gp1d

```
[-0.57735;
 0.57735];
```

This is the N1d that the program displays

```
[0.78868,   0.21132;
 0.21132,   0.78868];
```

This is the N1d I expected
`[ 0.78868, 0.78868 ];`

Comment: That makes no sense. How are you calling the function? That is likely where the issue is.

Comment: Of course I'm calling it in main.m as N = shapeFn1d(gp1d);

Comment: Can you [edit] the title of the question to make it easier to understand what you want/less generic ? (for people that don't open your question)

Comment: @Elikill58 just did, thanks.

Comment: Please add to the question a self-contained piece of code that calls this function and demonstrates the issue. See [mre]. I don’t see an issue with the code you posted, and don’t see an issue with the calling statement you shared in the comment. The issue must be around the calling code. Or maybe you are calling a different function with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere?  I copied and pasted your code and it seems fine, both in Octave and in Matlab:

```
>> system('cat shapeFn1d.m')
function N1d = shapeFn1d(gp1d)
  n1 = 0.5*(1-gp1d(1,1));
  n2 = 0.5*(1+gp1d(2,1));

  N1d = [n1, n2];
end
ans = 0
>> gp1d=[-0.57735; 0.57735];
>> shapeFn1d(gp1d)
ans =

   0.78868   0.78868

>>
```